# How to add a dynamic field with type schema in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a project where I have an Offer schema with a field of OfferType, which is also a schema, but I want to make it dynamic (OfferType), because each OfferType has some different fields.
I hope you got the idea.
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Wihout more info is not easy found an answer, but maybe use [mixed types](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) on `OfferType` schema can help you.

Comment: let's take a classified ads website, for example [this website](https://dubai.dubizzle.com) here you can add a new offer, and the offer may be of type Car, Bicycle, Job, Mobile...etc. and each offer type has some different fields, as we can see Cars has not the same specifications as Mobile. so I don't know how to achieve this with Mongodb. I hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an array inside `OfferType`. This will help you add many sub fields.

```
new mongoose.Schema({

OfferType: [
    field_name_1: {type:String, required:true}
    field_name_2: {type:Boolean, required:true}
    ...

]

})
```

Comment: I don't want to add sub fields, but I want to add only one dynamic field, for example I have Schema1 and Schema2, in the OfferType I want to add either Schema1 or Schema2